# Clickhouse-client insert optimization

Tags: database, csv, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I'm inserting a lot of CSV data files into remote Clickhouse database that already has a lot of data. I'm doing it using simple script like this:

```
...
 for j in *.csv; do
      clickhouse-client --max_insert_threads=32 --receive_timeout=30000 --input_format_allow_errors_num=999999999 --host "..." --database "..." --port 9000 --user "..." --password "..." --query "INSERT INTO ... FORMAT CSV" < "$j"
  done
...
```

So my question is: how to optimize these inserts? I already used these options for optimization:

```
--max_insert_threads=32 --receive_timeout=30000
```

Are there any more options in `clickhouse-client` I should use for better performance and for what purpose? One file can be like 300-500mb (and sometimes more). According to [this article](https://tech.marksblogg.com/faster-clickhouse-imports-csv-parquet-mysql.html) using parallel processes won't help that's why I'm inserting one file at time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

max_insert_threads is not applicable here, it's about `insert select` inside CH server.

> According to this article using parallel processes won't help

It should help (it depends on CPU and disk power), just try

```
# parallelism 6 (-P6)

find . -type f -name '*.csv' | xargs -P 6 -n 1 clickhouse-client --input_format_parallel_parsing=0 --receive_timeout=30000 --input_format_allow_errors_num=999999999 --host "..." --database "..." --port 9000 --user "..." --password "..." --query "INSERT INTO ... FORMAT CSV"
```

I set `input_format_parallel_parsing=0` deliberately, it improves total performance in case of multiple parallel loads.

Comment: Yeah, already did, it helped a little bit, but not that much, I will try this option you suggest, maybe it will help. What about max_insert_threads, I should delete it then if it won't help?

Comment: you can leave max_insert_threads it means nothing in this case.

Comment: How many CPU cores and what disks do you use? With powerful servers -P6 increases performance linearly - 6 times.

Comment: Also try `--compress=1` argument or `--compress=0`

Comment: I didn't find any information about ```--compress``` flag, can you tell what does it do or where to find information about it?

Comment: `clickhouse-client --help|grep compre
  --compression arg                                                    enable or disable compression
  --network_compression_method arg                                     Allows you to select the method of data compression when writing.
  --network_zstd_compression_level arg                                 Allows you to select the level of ZSTD compression.
` it compress network traffic between a client and a server

Comment: Thanks a lot, last question, I'm using 9000 port, just to make sure, what's better - http (8123) or 9000?

Comment: 9000 is TCP. 8123 is HTTP. No better or worse, they're just different. clickhouse-client able to use only 9000 (TCP), other libraries/applications only HTTP (for example official JDBC driver)

Comment: When trying this import I get: Code: 36. DB::Exception: Positional options are not supported. (BAD_ARGUMENTS)